# How to Exit a Process (.exec()) if the External Program hangs

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec, process-exit

Let me explain my software. What my software simply does is that it creates 10 threads and assigns a number of tasks to each thread. Each thread then creates a Runtime Process that will start a cmd batch file which in turn will start a program that will telnet to a device (I have about 200 of them) to poll its configuration. Here is the code for my process creation:

```
Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  start /b /wait " + batchFile); 
int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
```

`batchFile` is the full path of the batch file. Don't get me wrong, the software works fine up to 100% of the execution and it hanged **ONLY ONE TIME** at about 95%, so I'm trying to find a solution for that. Why it hanged is not my issue now, but rather how to deal with hangups later on..!

Now the problem is that I need to wait for the process to finish because my telnet client will write to a file that I will read later on in the thread; and hence the use of the `.waitFor()` . My question is how can I get the thread to understand that the external program hanged? In other words, can I give the external program some time limit to finish; and if it does not the thread will kill the process?

Also I have read about reading the error and output streams; however, I don't think it is applicable here, or is it?

Comment: *"Also I have read about reading the error and output streams; however, I don't think it is applicable here, or is it?"*  Most likely, yes.  Consume both of them and display them.

Comment: TBH, I have not tried cause I am assuming that they will not be of use because of the `waitfor()`. Won't it be called only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also I have read about reading the error and output streams; however, I don't think it is applicable here, or is it?

Almost certainly yes, it is applicable.  Try using `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec` and read all the output before calling `waitFor`.  For example (exception handling omitted, in particular `waitFor` may throw `InterruptedException` before the process actually exited)

```java
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd", "/c", "start", "/b", "/wait", batchFile);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(p.getOutputStream());
    IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
    // or alternatively throw away the output using
    // IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), NullOutputStream.NULL_OUTPUT_STREAM);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(p.getInputStream());
    int returnVal = p.waitFor();
```

(IOUtils and NullOutputStream are from [Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/)).

To answer the actual question in the title, if your process still hangs even after properly reading its output, you may need to use `p.destroy()` to forcibly terminate the process.  You could define a timer task something like

```java
    public class TimeoutProcessKiller extends TimerTask {
      private Process p;
      public TimeoutProcessKiller(Process p) {
        this.p = p;
      }

      public void run() {
        p.destroy();
      }
    }
```

and then do

```java
    // single shared timer instance
    Timer t = new Timer();

    // for each device
    Process p = pb.start();
    TimerTask killer = new TimeoutProcessKiller(p);
    t.schedule(killer, 30000);
    // ... read output stream as before ...
    int returnVal = p.waitFor();
    killer.cancel();
```

This will cause the process to be killed if it has been running for more than 30 seconds (adjust the `schedule` call to change the timeout).

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I was looking for to avoid an ANR in Android (after 5 seconds), so I've changed to t.schedule(killer, 4500);

Comment: With Java 8, it's also possible to use waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) which returns a boolean. (API 26 minimum in Android)

Comment: do we really have to call  int returnVal = p.waitFor();  at the end? can someone clarify if we have used t.schedule(killer, 30000);  then p.waitFor() at the end seems redundant.