# Connecting Java based GUI (Netbeans) with Python code (PyCharm)

Tags: java, python, user-interface, netbeans, pycharm

I want to know is there a way to connect my Java based GUI built on Netbeans to the Python code which consists of machine learning algorithms and NLTK for language processing. Basically, i need the GUI to upload files and display graphs and percetages based on the analytics completed by the Python code. **Basically, i need to call Python functions on button click actions.**

My other question is, can use QT GUI builder which is based on Python compleletly for the above mentioned tasks?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What are you wanting? To call python from java? Why is `PyCharm` included in this question at all?

Comment: This is what i want as it is clearly mentioned "connect my Java based GUI built on Netbeans to the Python code". Yes, i want to call Python code from my Java GUI. Pycharm was mentioned so that if any tool needs to be added for bridging users can mention resources according to my IDE.

Comment: If your question is purely about calling `Python` from `Java`, what have your tried? Is there any research effort you can show? Simply googling `Call python from java` provides [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java) different [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java) Did none of them work?

Comment: Yes, i have researched IPC bridging mechanisms and i find it not useful in implementing that in my system. I am asking suitable methods to proceed because i am new to this programming methods.  As you understand my question do you know any methods to proceed on my requirements?

Comment: Did you try anything in any of the links? Those are what the community has decided are the best solutions to your problem, and those are my initial recommendations. If you tried all of those methods and none of them worked for some specific reason then you should say that when asking the question. Because otherwise that is the only answer you are going to get (as shown below). No, I probably wont be able to help you.

Comment: Did you try anything in any of the links? Those are what the community has decided are the best solutions to your problem, and those are my initial recommendations. If you tried all of those methods and none of them worked for some specific reason then you should say that when asking the question. Because otherwise that is the only answer you are going to get (as shown below). No, I probably wont be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time much appreciated.

Comment: @Steveharvey I need to do the same thing I have a java GUI and a Python back-end that I want to connect. I was wondering if you were able to do that!

Answer (score -1):

If your question is "how can I call python code from Java", the answer is "Use Jython". Well the short answer is that.
[Calling Python in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java)

Comment: Jython doesn't support many Machine learning libraries i intend to use.