# How to call a python program in java using Runtime

Tags: java, python, runtime

I want to call a python program with arguments from java. But my output is a blank. The code is here.

Python code is here:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
```

And the java code is here:

```
public class PrintNumber{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Process proc;
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python ../pythonProgram/pythonProgram/PrintN.py 30");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

I want to output 30, could somebody tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java ?

Comment: Maybe the Python script is not found. To investigate you might read from `proc.getErrorStream` instead to see any error.

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes, you are totally correct, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it out:

```
String command = "python /c start python ../pythonProgram/pythonProgram/PrintN.py";

int param = 30;

proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command + param);
```

Reference: [Run Python script by Java](http://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java)

Comment: I kinda solve this problem, my issue is that I cannot run python code which imports a third-party library. So I need to find the full name of my python, which means I should code "which python" in terminal first, and then write down the full path. In this case, instead of "python ../pythonProgram/pythonProgram/PrintN.py 30", I should write down "/Users/archer/anaconda3/bin/python ../pythonProgram/pythonProgram/PrintN.py 30" and the first parameter is the outcome after "which python"