# I want to use a java project in python. On installing pip install pyjnius, it gives an error

Tags: java, python-3.x

```
pip install pyjnius
Collecting pyjnius
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/57/c90acf31322e6417f06c90410dbfcb149633a6006b7efbf99dfebe177c1f/pyjnius-1.2.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\dev1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dev1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uxkserni\\pyjnius\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dev1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uxkserni\\pyjnius\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Dev1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxkserni\pyjnius\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Dev1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxkserni\pyjnius\
    Complete output (18 lines):
    warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
    error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
    error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
    WARNING: Not able to assign machine() = AMD64 to a cpu value!
             Using cpu = 'i386' instead!
    JDK_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1

    JRE_HOME: None

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Dev1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxkserni\pyjnius\setup.py", line 246, in <module>
        compile_native_invocation_handler(JDK_HOME, JRE_HOME)
      File "C:\Users\Dev1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uxkserni\pyjnius\setup.py", line 96, in compile_native_invocation_handler
        join('jnius', 'src', 'org', 'jnius', 'NativeInvocationHandler.java')
      File "c:\users\dev1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-13.0.1\\bin\\javac.exe', '-target', '1.6', '-source', '1.6', 'jnius\\src\\org\\jnius\\NativeInvocationHandler.java']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java

Comment: This seems to be a known problem with pyjnius, see the bug reports at https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/issues/421 and https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/issues/418