# Get and parse output stream from Apache exec commons

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, apache-commons-exec

What I am trying to do is capture the stream of an IP Cam by using avconv. I have managed to get that stream and save it to a file using the apache exec commons library for Java like this:

```
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
String str = avconv_command; 
CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(str);
ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(1000000);
Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
```

With that, the avconv starts to capture the streaming and saves it to a file, and on the console I can see how the avconv is working and the output of the process. Each line of that output shows the duration of the video currently being captured, the bitrate, etc. I need to capture that output and process it while it is running. Any thoughts?

I have read many posts:

[Process output from apache-commons exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340452/process-output-from-apache-commons-exec)

[How can I capture the output of a command as a String with Commons Exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295866/how-can-i-capture-the-output-of-a-command-as-a-string-with-commons-exec)

But they all read the output when the process has finished, and I need to read it while it is running.

Comment: Figured it out.. Answer below

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with the following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PumpStreamHandler ps = new PumpStreamHandler(os);
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
String str = avconv_command; 
CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(str);
ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(1000000);
Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
executor.setStreamHandler(ps);
executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()));
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(reader);
String tmp = null;
while ((tmp = r.readLine()) != null) 
{
     //Do something with tmp line
}
```

So, I changed the output to a ByteArrayOutputStream, and then read that output. This block must be inside a loop so the byte array can update the content thas was generated from the output of the process