# Executing awk command in java

Tags: java, unix, awk

i am trying to execute awk command in java for linux/unix os but the thing is when i execute the command it does not show any error it.But after execution there is no output and it takes fraction of second to execute i dont know the problem please help .

the code is

```
process p =new process():
yes = "awk '{print $1}' /root/Desktop/net/net.zone >> /root/Desktop/net/net.txt";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(yes);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting command line processes correctly with Java isn't easy. I suggest you use [commons-exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) instead of trying it yourself.

Now you have two things in the command line which need special handing:

- Single quotes around the AWK script. When you pass each argument as a individual strings to `CommandLine` via `addArgument`, you don't need the quotes anymore.
- The output redirection.

  Since you create a child process, you are in control of stdin and stout. That means you need to open the target file for append in Java, wrap it in a `PumpStreamHandler` and pass that to `DefaultExecutor`. See this question for details: [Process output from apache-commons exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340452/process-output-from-apache-commons-exec)

Comment: Sir i am new to java cant understand what you are saying can u please elaborate

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation which I linked and work through the examples. If you don't know how to add a library to your project, your IDE's documentation should explain that.

Comment: @vigneshkalai since you are new to Java I suggest you ask in a Java forum how to do whatever it is you're trying to do. There's an excellent chance that calling awk is NOT the right approach.

Comment: thanks bro in stead using unix command i created a shell script and ran it