# Can i use awk in java?

Tags: java, awk

I tried the code below but it doesn't work. Nevertheless, if I try to cat the file, it works and prints the whole content of the file.

But the reason I tried using awk is that I don't need the whole content, I only need some parts of each line.

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("awk -F\":\" '/in/ {print $3}' file.awk"); 
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("esto es una \"prueba\"");
String valor = "";
while ((valor = in.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println(valor);
}
```

Comment: It isn't really an alternative to `awk`, but you can use `Pattern` / regex matcher to only print matching characters.

Comment: This topic is somewhat related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211696/executing-awk-command-in-java

Comment: Have you considered just extracting the data using Java?

Comment: Why do you need the `java` for? Why not just use `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to run `awk` for a problem that is so trivial? If the line contains the string "in", split it on ":" and return the third field:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
while(String line = reader.readLine()) {
    if (line.indexOf("in") >= 0) {
        String[] fields = line.split(":");
        System.out.println(fields[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not that simple, that code wouldn't work in my app, i could code my own "awk", but it would take a time i could spend coding more important things.

Comment: I've been thinking and maybe you are right, maybe i overdid my code, thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
jawk
```

is the java implementation of awk.
Please follow this link for an overview: http://jawk.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How do you suggest that JAWK be used to solve the problem?