# Unable to get output from Apache Commons Exec

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

Although the titles are very similar, this questions is **NOT** a duplicate of [Process output from apache-commons exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340452/process-output-from-apache-commons-exec).

I am trying to get the output of a command by using apache-commons exec. Here is what I am doing

```
import org.apache.commons.exec.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class Sample {


    private static void runCommand(String cmd) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PumpStreamHandler psh = new PumpStreamHandler(stdout);
        CommandLine cl = CommandLine.parse(cmd);
        DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
        exec.setStreamHandler(psh);
        exec.execute(cl);
        System.out.println(stdout.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        String cmd1 = "python -c \"print(10)\"";
        String cmd2 = "python -c \"import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now())\"";

        runCommand(cmd1); // prints 10
        runCommand(cmd2); // should print the current datetime, but does not!
    }
}
```

The problem is that `runCommand(cmd2)` does not print anything to the output. When I try running the command on terminal, it works fine.

I have tried this program with and without the IDE so I'm sure this has nothing to do with the IDE console.

Here's a screenshot

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the terminal

[image]

Python command running on the terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague was able to come up with a solution to this problem. Changing

```
CommandLine cl = CommandLine.parse(cmd);
```

to

```
CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
cl.addArguments("-c");
cl.addArguments("'" + cmd + "'", false);
```

solved the issue.

---

The complete code looks as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.exec.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class Sample {
    private static void runCommand(String cmd) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PumpStreamHandler psh = new PumpStreamHandler(stdout);

        // CommandLine cl = CommandLine.parse(cmd);
        CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
        cl.addArguments("-c");
        cl.addArguments("'" + cmd + "'", false);

        DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
        exec.setStreamHandler(psh);
        exec.execute(cl);
        System.out.println(stdout.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String cmd1 =  "python -c \"print(10)\"";
        String cmd2 =  "python -c \"import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now())\"";

        runCommand(cmd1); // prints 10
        runCommand(cmd2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on mine PC from IDEA. Try to recreate the project. Add more information about your environment.
Try to put your python code into .py file and run it like "python test.py".

[image: screen]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157525/discussion-on-answer-by-woland-unable-to-get-output-from-apache-commons-exec).